# Connected metric space with at least two points is uncountable.

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I solved this problem in the baby rudin as follows:

take any point p in the metric space X and suppose X is at most countable. there must be r such that the set of all points q in X satisfying d(p,q)=r is empty. If not, X will be uncountable.

so X can be partitioned into two sets: B, the set of all points q in X such that d(p,q) >r and A, the set of all points q in X such that d(p,q) is strictly less than r

then A,B are open in X, disjoint in X. so X is disconnected, a contradiction. 
so X is uncountable.

is this solution has any fallacy? any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to ensure that the open sets are non empty. You are given two points $p_1,p_2$, so choose $r \in (0,d(p_1,p_2))$, then you know that the two open sets are non empty.

Comment: aha! that will work since interval is uncountable! thanks for your help :)

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Almost there, but one problem: *You don't use the fact that X has at least two points*, and – in a sense, because of that – you can't guarantee that both A and B are nonempty, which you need for X to be disconnected.

Let $p_0, p_1$ be two distinct points in X, and let $r_0 = \mathsf{d}(p_0, p_1)$, so $r_0 > 0$.

*The rest is a tweaked version of your proof that takes $r_0$ into account.*

For $r \ge 0$ let $D_r = \{p \in X \mid \mathsf{d}(p_0, q) = r\}$.

Suppose X is countable. Then so is $\bigcup_{r \le r_0} D_r$. The $D_r$ are pairwise disjoint, so for some $s \le r_0$, $D_s$ must be $\emptyset$. As $D_{r_0} \neq \emptyset$, we must have $s < r_0$.

Let $A = \bigcup_{r < s} D_r$ and $B = \bigcup_{r > s} D_r$
Then $p_0 \in A$, $p_1 \in D_{r_0} \subseteq B$, so both are nonempty, and are open. Thus $X = A \cup B$ is not connected.

Comment: It seems that you missed something in the definition of $D_r$. And also $A$.

Comment: @JohnMa Yep - spotty connection tonight and I didn't see a real preview while I typed. Cleaned up now. Thanks.